# Upgraded to 15.04 after manually install graphics driver, system now hangs on login screen

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, 15.04

Based on the symptoms, I believe this is an issue with GRUB boot flags, or perhaps something to do with the graphics driver.

I'm running a GeForce GTX 750Ti, and installed the driver for it manually so I could see what I was doing in order to install the package managed one.

When I boot normally, I get to the login screen, but it flashes like crazy, isn't the right resolution, the Ubuntu drum sound plays over and over again, and my fan spins up to a speed I've never heard it go before.

Here's the weird part (which leads me to believe it's something with GRUB)... If I boot into recovery mode, then select the option `Resume Boot`, it boots fine. No graphics issues, no hang, no repeating sound, no fan spin up.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else had manually installed an Nvidia driver prior to upgrading and experiences this problem, here is what I did:

1. Boot into recovery mode
2. Enable networking (mounts filesystem writeable as well)
3. Go to root prompt and uninstall manually installed driver (`./NVIDIA-installer-name-here.run --uninstall`)
4. `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`
5. `nvidia-xconfig`
6. `reboot`